# How can I receive a string from the user and allocate it into a pointer array without any additional variables?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to get a string from the user and allocate it into a `char**` array at the same time, and I don't want to use any additional variables. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "middleman variable"? And what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: Is "middleman variable" a synonym for pointer?

Comment: You cannot allocate/assign a string into a pointer array. You only can use pointers to access pointed `char` arrays in which you store the strings.

Comment: when I said middleman variable I meant I don't want to malloc into a variable then put the variable into the string i want to do it directly into the string. I tried doing a malloc to the whole string and realloc to every string but that isn't really what I wanted to do. and I tried googling about it but found nothing useful

Comment: @G0rdo1 Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can understand what you mean.

Comment: This sounds like an  [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve??

Comment: I was thinking about using fgets and instead of giving a variable name to use malloc but that generates 2 problems, the one is that I don't know the size of the string so I will have to realloc to optimize memory usage and second is that I will have no way of knowing what pointer the malloc returned there for that memory will be lost

Answer (score 2):

Assuming middleman variable means an additional variable, the following code doesn't  use any additional variables. The answer below won't work if the max size of string is unknown.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char** stringArray = malloc(sizeof(char*)*100); //100 is length of string array

    stringArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*2000); //2000 is max string length

    scanf("%s",stringArray[0]);
    printf("String Received: %s\n",stringArray[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why in the line 'char** stringArray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*100)' the char before the malloc is char** and not char*?

Comment: @G0rdo1 Its a string array so it should be of type String*. String however is char*. So I wrote it as char**